# i am getting a "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" when i try to run it in net-beans. why is that happening?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jvm, japplet

```
package airlinep;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
public class NewClass1 extends JApplet{
JButton b1; 
  JButton b2; 

  JLabel lbl; 
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                guiInit();//throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
            }
        }); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("could not generate due to "+ex.toString());
    } 
    }

public void start()
{}
public void stop()
{}
public void destroy()
{}
private void guiInit()
{
//setLayout(new FlowLayout());
b1.setText("b1");
b2.setText("b2");
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
         lbl.setText(b1.getText()+" was pressed at ");//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
});
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
         lbl.setText(b2.getText()+" was pressed at ");//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
});
getContentPane().add(b1);
getContentPane().add(b2);
getContentPane().add(lbl);
}
}
```

when the program is run in netbeans the applet window is showing but no gui elements can not be seen like buttons.and in the console i can see that a exception has been caught by the try catch block.why am i getting this exception and what can i do so that this does not occur.

Comment: Change `System.out.println("could not generate due to "+ex.toString());` to `ex.printStackTrace();` and report the entire trace.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson AFAIK SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait couldn't be used for (J)Applet, may be am I wrong, please correct me if ...

Comment: @mKorbel *"SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait couldn't be used for (J)Applet,.."*  It actually **should** be done that way in an applet.  Using `invokeLater(..)` leaves the risk that `start()` will be called before the `init()` actions have completed.

Comment: @mKorbel `invokeAndWait` is kind of necessary because you need this code to be run on the EDT, and to do it before returning to the applet thread. ;( I wouldn't want to use it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a NullPointerException that you're not seeing because you're not catching exceptions correctly. You must assign objects to your reference variables, including your JButton and JLabel variables, **before** trying to use them.

In other words, change

```
JButton b1; 
JButton b2; 

JLabel lbl;
```

to

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("something"); 
JButton b2 = new JButton("something else"); 

JLabel lbl = new JLabel("something else entirely");
```

---

Also to capture the missed target exception, consider doing:

```
  try {
     SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           guiInit();
        }
     });
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
     e.getTargetException().printStackTrace(); // get the target exception
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```